# Grid of list elements of multiple lists

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve a calculator-like icon layout on a mobile navmenu.
The icons should display like on a mobile phone home screen, 3 columns and as many rows as needed for all the list items.
Now, if a list only has 2 items for example, that fill column 1 and 2, I want the next list to start in the empty column 3. If it has more than 1 item, it should go to the next row and fill up that row. Is there a way to achieve this with css only?

I've tried the attached flex and grid layouts, but get stuck because I can't get the behaviour mentioned before. I also don't wanna assign the columns and rows that items are on with template areas, because the items in the lists are dynamic and can vary from page to page.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Restriction: I can't edit the HTML and enclose all `<li>` elements in one `<ol>`

My HTML:

```
<div class="entries">
  <ol>
    <li>1a</li>
    <li>2a</li>
    <li>3a</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>4b</li>
    <li>5b</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>6c</li>
    <li>7c</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>8d</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>9e</li>
    <li>10e</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

My Grid CSS:

```
.entries {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: 500px;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

[Codepen of Grid Layout](https://codepen.io/ticklish__/pen/PoLeJbo)
[Codepen of Flex Layout](https://codepen.io/ticklish__/pen/NWJMxdV)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by "opening" the `ol` by using [`display: contents`](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents) and then using `display: grid` on the wrapping div container.

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.entries {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  display: contents;
}

li {
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="entries">
  <ol>
    <li>1a</li>
    <li>2a</li>
    <li>3a</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>4b</li>
    <li>5b</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>6c</li>
    <li>7c</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>8d</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>9e</li>
    <li>10e</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually does exactly what I want, but caniuse says that buttons become not accessible with this property and I do have links inside the list elements. So better not use in production, right?
https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

Answer (score 0):

You may change your CSS a little bit like:

```css
        .entries {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);    

        /* grid-template-rows: 1fr; */
        width: 500px;
        }

        ol {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        gap: 20px;
        margin: 10px 0;

        /* display:grid; */
        /* grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); */
        }
```

```html
    <div class="entries">
        <ol>
          <li>1a</li>
          <li>2a</li>
          <li>3a</li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
          <li>4b</li>
          <li>5b</li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
          <li>6c</li>
          <li>7c</li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
          <li>8d</li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
          <li>9e</li>
          <li>10e</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
```

Does this serve your purpose?

Comment: this change makes the `<ol>` elements into columns with vertical rows of `<li>`elements. this isn't what i wanna achieve unfortunately. thank you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

You could remove all those `ol` and leave onle one that wraps all `<li>` items, and it could be done easily. And leaving your grid (or flex) CSS rules untouched.

```css
.entries {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: 500px;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
 <div class="entries">
    <ol>
      <li>1a</li>
      <li>2a</li>
      <li>3a</li>
      <li>4b</li>
      <li>5b</li>
      <li>6c</li>
      <li>7c</li>
      <li>8d</li>
      <li>9e</li>
      <li>10e</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```